# SwiftUI List messed up after delete action on iOS 15

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

It seems that there is a problem in SwiftUI with `List` and deleting items. The items in the list and data get out of sync.

This is the code sample that reproduces the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var popupShown = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show list") { popupShown.toggle() }
            if popupShown {
                MainListView()
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: popupShown)
    }
}

struct MainListView: View {
    @State var texts = (0...10).map(String.init)

    func delete(at positions: IndexSet) {
        positions.forEach { texts.remove(at: $0) }
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(texts, id: \.self) { Text($0) }
                .onDelete { delete(at: $0) }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}
```

If you perform a delete action on the first row and scroll to the last row, the data and list contents are not in sync anymore.

This is only happening when animation is attached to it. Removing `.animation(.easeInOut, value: popupShown)` workarounds the issue.

This code sample works as expected on iOS 14 and doesn't work on iOS 15.

Is there a workaround for this problem other then removing animation?

Answer (score 1):

<s>It isn't the `animation()`. The clue was seeing</s> It appears that having the `.animation` outside of the conditional causes the problem. Moving it to the view itself corrected it to some extent. However, there is a problem with this `ForEach` construct: `ForEach(texts, id: \.self)`. As soon as you start deleting elements of your array, the UI gets confused as to what to show where. You should ALWAYS use an `Identifiable` element in a `ForEach`. See the example code below:

```
struct ListDeleteView: View {
    @State var popupShown = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show list") { popupShown.toggle() }
            if popupShown {
                MainListView()
                    .animation(.easeInOut, value: popupShown)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainListView: View {
    @State var texts = (0...10).map({ TextMessage(message: $0.description) })

    func delete(at positions: IndexSet) {
        texts.remove(atOffsets: positions)
    }


    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(texts) { Text($0.message) }
                .onDelete { delete(at: $0) }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}

struct TextMessage: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let message: String
}
```

Comment: In addition to that, I'd recommend replacing `positions.forEach { texts.remove(at: $0) }` with `texts.remove(atOffsets: positions)`. If `positions` ever had more than one index in it, you'd end up removing the wrong objects since an array's indices change when you remove an object from the array.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and I am adding that to my answer. Also, my original answer had the issue again. It seems to be intermittent. I moved the `.animation` onto `MainListView()` and it seemed to correct it.

Comment: But moving animation to `MainListView` doesn't animate the appearance of the list, which is something that we would like.
In this particular example, `Identifiable` shouldn't be a problem as all elements are different, and `\.self` should produce a unique value for each.